# What are some tips for shooting down spy planes?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops

I heard its possible to shoot down a spy plane, but when they are deployed I can't even see them.  Where on the map do they normally hang out, in the center, or does it move?  Tips for shooting it down?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are fairly easy to spot [bigger than mw2], you just have to check out the skies for a moment. Here is a [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YDr_cQVswa4), so that you know what to look for.

Answer (score 8):

**Location**
They appear in any direction, but as far as I remember they fly clockwise with an approximately 60-70° angle from the ground.

**Shooting them down**
Keep an M72 or the Strela-3 ready as a secondary weapon to engage them without hassle, or focus fire with a light machine gun. If none available, they should go down in 2 cartridges of ammo from an assault rifle.

Comment: Cool, what do they look like?  Easily visible?  Or are they hard to see?

Comment: @Brian they are pretty easy to spot, they look like a small plane that slowly circles the map

Comment: @Brian it is also important to note you will find them fastest by rotating counter-clockwise (because the plane is flying clockwise)

Comment: @Brian If you're having difficulty seeing them, use your Strela or M72 and hold down the aim button as you rotate counter-clockwise. Listen for the launcher to start beeping. Once you know what you are looking for they are very easy to pick out, but some maps have severly reduced skyline visibility.

Comment: @Aardvark Interesting methodology :) They are pretty slow flyers, so I find it doesn't really matter which way around you turn. Ymmv.

Answer (score 0):

As has been mentioned, spy planes are visible. In **black-ops**, if you can get the **SAM turret care package**, position it in an obscure part of the map, and it will keep shooting down enemy spy planes until the enemy takes out the turret.

But I don't think you can take out the SR71.

Answer (score 0):

Hiding- I don't now if it's possible, although you could try hiding inside of a building with a roof. Although if it does work, you would have to be in a concealed area if you plan on camping to kill enemies, and those aren't easy to find inside buildings where you can still se enemies.

Destroying- They are very easy to spot once you know what you're looking for. The best weapons for destroying them are strela-3s, M72s, and other certain non-care package explosive weapons. Or just you a SAM turret or Counter Spy Planes or a Blackhack.